# How to generate certificates for (secondary) compile puppetserver?

Tags: ssl-certificate, puppet, puppetmaster

I'm trying to [scale puppetserver](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/server/scaling_puppet_server.html), in order to have redundancy, using round robin DNS. The secondary `puppetserver` (version `7.4.0`) is configured to use the CA authority from primary `puppetserver`:

`/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf`:

```
[main]
ca_name = Puppet CA: puppet-ca-master.company.com
ca_server = puppet-ca-master.company.com
[agent]
server = puppet-ca-master.company.com
runinterval=1800
```

On the secondary server I've disabled CA service, as there could be only single certificate authority in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/services.d/ca.cfg`:

```
# To enable the CA service, leave the following line uncommented
# puppetlabs.services.ca.certificate-authority-service/certificate-authority-service
# To disable the CA service, comment out the above line and uncomment the line below
puppetlabs.services.ca.certificate-authority-disabled-service/certificate-authority-disabled-service
puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.services.watcher.filesystem-watch-service/filesystem-watch-service
```

I've removed certificates from the secondary, in order to fetch certificate signed certificate from the CA master:

```
rm -rf /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl && mkdir -p /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs
chmod 0700 /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
chown -R puppet /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
```

However the `puppetserver` service refuses to start because of missing certificate:

```
2021-09-30T09:06:18.220+02:00 ERROR [async-dispatch-2] [p.t.internal] Error during service start!!!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to open 'ssl-cert' file: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/secondary-puppetserver.company.com.pem
```

When I try to run `puppet agent -t` on the secondary puppetserver it fails to sign the certificate:

```
Couldn't fetch certificate from CA server; you might still need to sign this agent's certificate (secondary-puppetserver.company.com)
```

Moreover the private key gets generated, but not a public one:

```
ll /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/
total 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With round robin DNS CA master config `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d/ca.conf` needs to include:

```
allow-subject-alt-names: true
```

Restart `puppetserver` and generate certificates for secondary server on CA master:

```
puppetserver ca generate --certname puppet-secondary.company.com --subject-alt-names=puppet-secondary.company.com,puppet.company.com
```

transfer certificates:

```
rsync -a /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet-secondary.company.com.pem secondary-puppet:/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/
rsync -a /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet-secondary.company.com.pem secondary-puppet:/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/
rsync -a /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/puppet-secondary.company.com.pem secondary-puppet:/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/public_keys/
```

and CA

```
rsync -ra /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ca/{ca_crl.pem,ca_crt.pem} secondary-puppet:/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ca/
```

On secondary make sure that CA service is disabled in `/etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/services.d/ca.cfg`.

And make sure that webserver is configured to use correct certs `/etc/puppetlabspuppetserver/conf.d/webserver.conf`:

```
webserver: {
    access-log-config: /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/request-logging.xml
    client-auth: want
    ssl-host: 0.0.0.0
    ssl-port: 8140
    ssl-cert: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/puppet-secondary.company.com.pem
    ssl-key: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/puppet-secondary.company.com.pem
    ssl-ca-cert: /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ca/ca_crt.pem
    ssl-crl-path: /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ca/ca_crl.pem
}
```

On CA master DNS alt names could be verified. All puppet servers needs to include the same domain name and other unique name.

```
puppetserver ca list --all
```

look for `alt names: ["DNS: ...` . When certificate is generated using `puppet agent`, the alt names are not included.